# Analysis of a loop that has a variable expanding exponentially not by a constant amount

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, analysis

I know that if a loop variable expands exponentially by a constant exponent k it has a complexity of O(log(logn)). But I couldn't wrap my head around analyzing this function.

```
void foo{
int a=0;
 for(int i=2;i<=n;i++){
   if(i%2==0){
     a++;
   } else{
     i=(i-1)*i;
   }
 }
}
```

[I found this sequence fitting to the problem in hand](https://oeis.org/search?q=2+3+7+43+1807&sort=&language=&go=Search)

Comment: A good compiler will eliminate the body of the function since the result (`a`, presumably) is not used.  It should be `int foo` and should end with `return a`. It's a curious language, or pseudo-code, that you're using; it isn't clear where `n` comes from, but it might be an argument to the function. The loop is going to exit quickly as the squaring operation increases `i` very quickly, ignoring overflow. Since `i` will always be odd after the iteration with `i == 2` (because `(i - 1)*i` will be even, and `i++` ensures it is odd), the result is always `a == 1`. That's just eyeballing the code.

Comment: Thanks for spotting my logic error! Answer deleted, and I’ve replaced it with a new answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the values that `i` takes on over the iterations of the loop.

- Before the first iteration, `i` = 2.
- Before the second iteration, we have `i` = 3, since we compute skip the “else” branch and then add one.
- Before the third iteration, we have `i` = 7, since we compute `i = 3 * (3 - 1)` and then add one.
- Before the fourth iteration, we have `i` = 43, since we compute `i = 7 * (7 - 1)` and then add one.
- Before the fifth iteration, we have `i` = 1807, since we compute `i = 43 * (43 - 1)` and the add one.

In what I can only describe as a magical coincidence, I happen to recognize the sequence of numbers 2, 3, 7, 43, 1807 as the start of [Sylvester's sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_sequence), which I just learned about a few weeks ago. Checking Wikipedia confirms that, indeed, Sylvester's sequence is given by the recurrence relation

- S<sub>0</sub> = 2
- S<sub>n+1</sub> = S<sub>n</sub>(S<sub>n</sub> - 1) + 1.

It's known that this sequence grows doubly-exponentially, with S<sub>n</sub> approximately equal to E<sup>2<sup>n</sup></sup> for E = 1.264084735... . So this indeed means that the number of iterations of this algorithm as a function of n will be O(log log n), since `i` grows doubly-exponentially quickly.

But let's say that you didn't have the dumb luck of having found this exact sequence on a random Wikipedia search. Could you still show that the runtime is Θ(log log n)? The answer is yes, and here's one way to do it.

The first observation we can make is that this procedure will cause `i` to grow more slowly than if we instead set `i` = `i`<sup>2</sup>. You can check this by seeing the corresponding terms of what happens:

```
i = i(i - 1) + 1     2, 3, 7,   43, ...
i = i^2              2, 4, 16, 256, ...
```

If we were to grow `i` at this faster rate, then after k iterations of the loop we'd have `i` = 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>. (Notice that 2, 4, 16, 256, ... = 2<sup>2<sup>0</sup></sup>, 2<sup>2<sup>1</sup></sup>, 2<sup>2<sup>2</sup></sup>, ...). We stop once n = 2<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>, which happens after k = Θ(log log n) iterations. This provides a lower bound on how many steps this algorithm will take.

To get an upper-bound, imagine that we instead initialized `i` = 1.2 and then updated `i` = `i`<sup>2</sup> per iteration. Then we'd get these numbers:

```
i = i(i - 1) + 1       2,   3,   7,  43, ...
i = i^2              1.2, 1.4, 4.3, 18.5,
```

You can prove, if you'd like, that indeed the sequence you've come up with indeed continues to outpace this smaller sequence. And that smaller sequence has the nice property that the value of `i` on iteration k is (1.2)<sup>2<sup>k</sup></sup>, which means that we (again) stop after Θ(log log n) iterations.

In other words, our sequence is sandwiched between two different other sequences, each of which grows doubly-exponentially quickly, which means that this sequence too grows doubly-exponentially quickly. Therefore, this loop stops after Θ(log log n) steps.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I wish you hadn't deleted the previous answer, even if it wasn't exactly the answer, it was a great insight.

Comment: If I get a free moment today I’ll incorporate the insights from that answer into this one.